# What do I need to download to use MFC without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, mfc

I've got Visual Studio 2008 express, and I need to use afx.h and some other things from MFC. Is there an SDK I can download that includes those? I downloaded the latest Windows SDK, but that didn't include it.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, sorry for my english... i dont know speak english... I believe this link above can help you...
you only will need to configure another IDE, but MFC comes with WDK too...
i've made with CodeBlocks and it works fine... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30439/How-to-compile-MFC-code-in-Visual-C-Express Good Luck!
Igor RF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC is the proprietary class collection for Microsoft paid customer so I don't think you can get them FOC (well legally of course).

You can consider Win32++ which attempt to mimic MFC functionalities and its open source.

Comment: completely wrong, MFC is free and redistributable : https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/distributable-code-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-rc-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-sdk-rc-includes-utilities-buildserver-files/

Answer (score 2):

MFC isn't free. You should buy at least Standard Edition of the Visual Studio.

Comment: completely wrong, MFC is free and redistributable : https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/distributable-code-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-rc-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-sdk-rc-includes-utilities-buildserver-files/

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old but i felt i needed to spread some truth and negate some of the fantasies about MFC :

Its is completely free and always will be. You simply need to deploy the REDIST packages instead of your MSVC library as described here :

### MFC:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/redistributing-the-mfc-library

---

### VS2017 DK libraries:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/2017-redistribution-vs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/redistributing-visual-cpp-files

---

### VS2015 DK libraries :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx

https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/distributable-code-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-rc-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-sdk-rc-includes-utilities-buildserver-files/

Comment: This sounds promising. Do you have a hint how these redistributable files could be used to compile an MFC application with msbuild? (alas without installing Visual Studio  itself) Is there some package I can't find to be installed?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/redistributing-the-mfc-library?view=vs-2017

Comment: That's the same link like above, right? To my knowledge the redistributables are not enough to build the application. You will need excerpts from the VS installation - which are also permitted to copy (e.g. to the build server).

Comment: No, noone needs "excerpts from the VS installation", that would'nt even make sense

Comment: The headers (e.g.) are required to compile. They are not included in the redistributables. So where do you get them from?

Comment: let me get this straight : you actually want to compile your app with an included library (MFC) without having to reference or include the library ... ? Thats nonsensical. Link your lib statically or dynamically and you're done. If you want to link it dynamically you need to add it to your deployment (in this case : via the REDIST package). It has been like that for decades

Comment: No, no. No special things. Dynamic linking is fine. Still, for compiling the dll is not enough. You also need the headers. At runtime (once the app is compiled) the dlls from the redistributable package are enough.